# Failed to create IXPlaceholder Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to launch my apps that were working earlier without any issue but after I updated Xcode & Simulator, I keep getting this error and none of my apps seem to be working. They build without issue but when trying to launch them, nothing happens and this error comes up.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID co.appbrewery.Tipsy
Domain: IXErrorDomain
Code: 2
Failure Reason: Failed to create promise.
User Info: {
FunctionName = "+[IXPlaceholder _placeholderForBundle:client:withParent:installType:metadata:error:]";
SourceFileLine = 503;
}

Comment: any solution you got it?

Comment: installed XCode 11.4, works without issue.

Comment: I get the same error with Xcode 12.4 and the iOS 14.4 simulators do not work - only iOS 13.3. Can't find the answer anywhere on Google either.

Comment: Try switching back to 11.4 or 12

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo xcrun simctl shutdown all && sudo xcrun simctl erase all
```

this should work https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653807

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I had cycling errors and this was one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to 11.4 and it worked fine. No other solution worked for me.